# Is there any way to update a specific array object in reducer in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

Here I am trying to update my state data with a reducer. I am sending an object through dispatch which is consisted of id, and some data. By this id, I am trying to update a specific object of my state. My state reducer is,

```
case "UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        users: state.users.map((user) => {
          if (user.id !== action.payload.id) {
            return user;
          } else {
            return {
              ...user,
              ...action.payload,
            };
          }
        }),
      };
```

Here is the action,

```
export const updateUser = (updatedUser) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({
    type: "UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS",
    payload: updatedUser,
  });
  console.log(updateUser);
  localStorage.setItem(
    "Users",
    JSON.stringify(getState().addUserReducer.users)
  );
};
```

ANd my dispatching is from here,

```
const formHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(updateUser(updatedUser));
    console.log(name + email + phone + roles);
  };
```

Comment: Where do you use this `users` array? Please share the code of that component too, and the code how you dispatch this action.

Comment: Is the map function is okay here?

Comment: Map function seems fine at-a-glance. What is the issue you face?

Comment: `map` function seems correct

Comment: Please check it again, i have added my action and dispatch functions.

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is, and also what the value of `updatedUser` is that you are dispatching?

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

```
    return {
              ...user,
              ...action.payload,
            };
```

what is your goal here? If user was an array, by utilizing this code , you would add `action.payload` to your array. But user is an object. If you want to pass another object to it, you have to give it a key:

```
    return {
              ...user,
              whateverkey:action.payload,
            };
```

and your user objcect has a new key-value pair.
furthermore: if you want easier access further on you can use this as well:

```
    return {
              ...user,
             id:action.payload.id,
             name:action.payload.name,
             address:action.payload.address

            };
```

Comment: The spread syntax (`...action.payload`) is perfectly valid here to spread in the key-values from `action.payload`.

Comment: This worked for me perfectly, I added manually key-value pairs. Thanks.

Comment: @DrewReese I tested it and here is the result. This works:
```const ob = {
    name: "sobhan",
    lastname: "jahanmard",
  };
  const obb = {
    name: "sobhann",
    lastname: "jahanmardd",
  };
  const func = () => {
    return { ...ob, whatevername: obb };
  };
  console.log(func());```
 but if you change the return to this, it does not.
```return { ...ob, ...obb};```